# Downloading Video from Website

Tags: video-streaming

Ubuntu 16.04: I have used youtube-dl to successfully download videos, so that they can be watched sans network connectivity

I would like to download the set of videos from the USPTO:

https://www.uspto.gov/video/cbt/efswebtraining/index.htm

Is there a more general class of utilities that perform this function?  Suggestions to tackle the goal are appreciated.

Comment: I visited the site and it asked me to turn on Adobe Flash. I did not turn it on, but if the videos you want to download are Adobe Flash files, then they are not just videos.

Comment: Can the flash files be download and played?  I would like to be able to view the video on an airplane (assume no network connectivity).